# How to control the axis interval in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have the following equation

```
p = 1.6; α = 0.001; r = 0.6; η = 0.04; ω = 1;
R ω p Sin[ω τ] + R ω p α - 9/4 r p R^3 ω - η p R == 0
```

If I use the following command

```
ContourPlot[R ω p Sin[ω τ] + R ω p α - 9/4 r p R^3 ω - η p R == 0, 
   {τ, 0, 20}, {R, 0, 2}, ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick]}]
```

I am getting a plot where the x axis values are displayed at an interval of 5, i.e 0,5,10...., Is it possible to control the x axis interval ,like 0,2,4. Please suggest.

Comment: Probably, you are looking for the options `Ticks` or `FrameTicks`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the internal functions `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and  `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` to control how many tick marks are displayed. For example:

```
ContourPlot[
    R ω p Sin[ω τ]+R ω p α-9/4 r p R^3 ω-η p R == 0,
    {τ, 0, 20},
    {R, 0, 2},
    ContourStyle->{Directive[Blue,Thick]},
    FrameTicks->{
        {Automatic,Automatic},
        {
        Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}][0,20,{10,2}],
        Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}][0,20,{10,2}]
        }
    }
]
```

[image]

The third argument, `{10, 2}` specifies that approximately 10 major divisions and 2 minor divisions per major division should be used.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `ContourPlot` is a framed plot that by default doesn't show axes ticks. What you need to do is define a set of custom frame ticks. Like so.

```
tickF[f_Function, min_, max_] := f /@ Range[Floor @ min, Floor @ max]
btmTicks[min_, max_] := tickF[{#, If[Mod[Round @ #, 2] == 0, #, ""]} &, min, max]
topTicks[min_, max_] := tickF[{#, "" } &, min, max]

p = 1.6; α = 0.001; r = 0.6; η = 0.04; ω = 1;
ContourPlot[
  R ω p Sin[ω τ] + R ω p α - 9/4 r p R^3 ω - η p R, {τ, 0, 20}, {R, 0, 2},
  Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> False,
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Thick]},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {btmTicks, topTicks}}]
```

[image: plot]

Note: I have changed the 1st argument given to `ContourPlot` from the form `expression == 0` to the form `expression` and added additional contour options because my version of Mathematica (V11.1.1) has a bug that produces a horrible looking and incorrect tooltip value for the contours. These changes are a work-around that produces the correct tooltip. Your version of Mathematica may not have this paticular bug and, if so, you can ignore those changes.